# Cannot install Kernel Security updates in 14.10

Tags: kernel, updates, 14.10, security, update-manager

I cannot install some security updates to Ubuntu 14.10 (Utopic Unicorn) 64bit, which are kernel updates.

[image: The Kernel Updates]

Those are the updates.

[image: Error Message]

I cannot install them. In settings, I have everything ticked. Also, sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade does not install them, everything else, including other security updates. Help would be very much appreciated.

Thank you for your time and answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command that I was missing was:

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

done. fixed.